# Parsing text document and print in c++

Tags: c++, parsing, document

i want to parse my text file and to print only specified data form it. In my document i search data from line DATE TIME TERMINAL to line PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE and print it. But now i want to customize my output and to collecting all notes form all clients(Total notes = usd 1,usd 2,usd 10,usd 20,usd 1,usd 3..= 1+2+10+20+1+3+5+10), total notes =52. And the output to be look like

```
OUTPUT File: 

Total notes: 52
==============================
1.  Client: 123456******3381
DATE: 13.03.2019 TIME: 11:50 
1 х 50 USD
2 х 100 USD

2.  Client: 123456******3381
Date: 13.03.2019 Time: 12:23 
5 х 10 USD
10 x 20 USD

2.  Client: 123456******3381
Date: 13.03.2019 Time: 08:45 
1 х 10 USD
3 x 20 USD
5 x 50 USD
10 x 100 USD
==============================
```

```
....
....
        while (getline(input, line))
        {  
            //count++;

            pos = line.find("DATA/DATE");
            pos2 = line.find("PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE");
            card = line.find("ID:");
            char arr[] = "ID:";
            found = line.find(arr, found + 1);
            //if (found != string::npos)

                if (pos != string::npos) // string::npos is returned if string is not found
                {


                          outFile.open("outfile.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
                          outFile << count << ". Client: \n" << endl;
                          outFile << "DATA/DATE      TIME     TERMINAL" << endl;

                          while (getline(input, line))
                          {


                                   cout << line << endl;

                                  outFile << line << endl;
                                    string::size_type middle_begin = line.find(" USD") + 1;
                                    string::size_type middle_end = line.find("\n", middle_begin);
                                    string middle = line.substr(middle_begin, middle_end - middle_begin);
                                    cout  << middle << endl;
                                    int c;
                                    c = atoi(middle.c_str());
                                    cout << c << endl;

                                  if (line == "PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE") {
                                      outFile << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
                                      outFile << "\n" << endl;
                                      count++;
                                      goto BEGIN;

                                  }

                          }


                }
outFile.close();

        }
    }
    system("notepad /p outfile.txt");


}
```

```
My output:

1. Client: 

DATA/DATE      TIME     TERMINAL
2019.07.16     20:07:27     TID00302 
----------------------------------------
ID: 123456******3381
AID: A0000000043060

**************************************

PLEASE KEEP THIS RECEIPT
AND CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
**************************************

NOTES:

50  USD 1                     
100  USD 2             

PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
----------------------------------------


2. Client: 

DATA/DATE      TIME     TERMINAL
2019.07.16     20:07:27     TID00302 
----------------------------------------
CARD: 123456******3381
AID: A0000000043060

**************************************

PLEASE KEEP THIS RECEIPT
AND CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
**************************************

NOTES:

5  USD 10                     
10  USD 20            

PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
----------------------------------------


3. Client: 

DATA/DATE      TIME     TERMINAL
2019.07.16     20:07:27     TID00302 
----------------------------------------
ID: 123456******3381
AID: A0000000043060

**************************************

PLEASE KEEP THIS RECEIPT
AND CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
**************************************

NOTES:

10  USD 1                     
20  USD 3 
50  USD 5  
100 USD 10          

PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
----------------------------------------
```

```
INPUT FILE:
....
Some other text
APPROVAL CODE:1264
Decline reason message:  Common decline
=================================================
10:22:23 INFORMATION REQUEST AB    C 
10:22:24 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT  FUNCTION 5
10:22:32 INFORMATION REQUEST AA      
10:22:32 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 0 FUNCTION 100
10:22:35 INFORMATION REQUEST AC 
10:22:36 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 016 FUNCTION 
10:22:45 INFORMATION REQUEST B DA 
10:22:45 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 021 
10:22:52 INFORMATION REQUEST  A AA CB
10:22:53 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 104 FUNCTION 2047

================ INFO ================
2018.07.18 10:23:41  - 4784
IDCR: 1111520
SOLUTION: A:5 B:5 C:5
=================================================
DATA/DATE      TIME     TERMINAL
2019.07.16     20:07:27     TID00302 
----------------------------------------
ID: 123456******3381
AID: A0000000043060

**************************************

PLEASE KEEP THIS RECEIPT
AND CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
**************************************

NOTES:

50  USD 1                     
100  USD 2             

PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
----------------------------------------
10:23:09 INFORMATION REQUEST AB
10:23:09 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 010 FUNCTION 5000
10:39:42 INFORMATION REQUEST AA      
10:39:42 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 500 FUNCTION 5000
10:39:48 INFORMATION REQUEST AC A  B 
10:39:49 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 016 FUNCTION 5000
10:39:51 INFORMATION REQUEST B DAA B 
10:39:51 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 021 FUNCTION 5000
10:40:04 INFORMATION REQUEST  A AA BB
10:40:04 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 620 FUNCTION 5000
10:40:06 INFORMATION REQUEST    ACCBB

================ INFO ================
2018.07.18 10:40:41  - 1235
IDCR: 1111220
SOLUTION: A:5 B:5 C:5
=================================================
10:22:23 INFORMATION REQUEST AB    C 
10:22:24 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT  FUNCTION 5
10:22:32 INFORMATION REQUEST AA      
10:22:32 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 0 FUNCTION 100
10:22:35 INFORMATION REQUEST AC 
10:22:36 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 016 FUNCTION 
10:22:45 INFORMATION REQUEST B DA 
10:22:45 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 021 
10:22:52 INFORMATION REQUEST  A AA CB
10:22:53 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 104 FUNCTION 2047
DATA/DATE      TIME     TERMINAL
2019.07.16     20:07:27     TID00302 
----------------------------------------
CARD: 123456******3381
AID: A0000000043060

**************************************

PLEASE KEEP THIS RECEIPT
AND CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
**************************************

NOTES:

5  USD 10                     
10  USD 20            

PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
----------------------------------------
APPROVAL CODE:
Decline reason message:  Common decline
=================================================
10:22:23 INFORMATION REQUEST AB    C 
10:22:24 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT  FUNCTION 5
10:22:32 INFORMATION REQUEST AA      
10:22:32 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 0 FUNCTION 100
10:22:35 INFORMATION REQUEST AC 
10:22:36 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 016 FUNCTION 
10:22:45 INFORMATION REQUEST B DA 
10:22:45 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 021 
10:22:52 INFORMATION REQUEST  A AA CB
10:22:53 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 104 FUNCTION 2047
APPROVAL CODE:
Decline reason message:  Common decline
=================================================
10:22:23 INFORMATION REQUEST AB    C 
10:22:24 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT  FUNCTION 5
10:22:32 INFORMATION REQUEST AA      
10:22:32 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 0 FUNCTION 100
10:22:35 INFORMATION REQUEST AC 
10:22:36 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 016 FUNCTION 
10:22:45 INFORMATION REQUEST B DA 
10:22:45 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 021 
10:22:52 INFORMATION REQUEST  A AA CB
10:22:53 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 104 FUNCTION 2047
DATA/DATE      TIME     TERMINAL
2019.07.16     20:07:27     TID00302 
----------------------------------------
ID: 123456******3381
AID: A0000000043060

**************************************

PLEASE KEEP THIS RECEIPT
AND CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
**************************************

NOTES:

10  USD 1                     
20  USD 3 
50  USD 5  
100 USD 10          

PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
----------------------------------------
APPROVAL CODE:
Decline reason message:  Common decline
=================================================
10:22:23 INFORMATION REQUEST AB    C 
10:22:24 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT  FUNCTION 5
10:22:32 INFORMATION REQUEST AA      
10:22:32 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 0 FUNCTION 100
10:22:35 INFORMATION REQUEST AC 
10:22:36 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 016 FUNCTION 
10:22:45 INFORMATION REQUEST B DA 
10:22:45 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 021 
10:22:52 INFORMATION REQUEST  A AA CB
10:22:53 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 104 FUNCTION 2047
```

Comment: The code is a bit of a mess, it could do with a rewrite before you attempt this new task. The clear improvment you should make is to separate out the parsing of the data from the printing of the parsed data. **First** parse the input file putting the items that you find into suitable data structures, **then** output the data you want in the format you want. The way you have everything mixed together makes the code hard to understand and almost impossible to modify to  do new tasks.

Comment: And of course, you should write multiple functions with helpful names to solve this task. Putting everything into one large main function is (frankly) a bit amateurish. At the very least you could have three functions, `main`, `parse_input` and `print_output`.

Comment: Can you please show your input file? ANd maybe explain a little bit better?

Comment: Here is my input text file. It's a log file with date, time and some info. I want to customize output file and to collecting this usd notes. I try to find this USD in input file with `string::size_type middle_begin = line.find(" USD") + 1;` (USD 1, USD 2..) and to convert string  to integer with `atoi(middle.c_str());` but got some errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lts see a complete code example that well solve your problem. After the listing, I will explain a littel bit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

struct ClientData
{
    // The clients data. Everything stored as string
    std::string id{};
    std::string date{};
    std::string time{};
    // The notes will bes trored in a map. Key is not type and value is note count
    std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> notes{};
    // Get the overall number of notes for thiy record
    size_t getNumberOfNotes() const { size_t sum{ 0 }; for (auto const& [k, v] : notes) sum += v; return sum; }

    // Read and parse parts of the input file
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, ClientData& cd);

    // Out put function. Print data in required format
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, ClientData& cd) {
        os << "   Client: " << cd.id << "\nDATE: " << cd.date << " Time: " << cd.time;;
        for (auto const& [k, v] : cd.notes) os << '\n' << v << " x " << k << " USD";
        return os;
    }
};

// The inserter operator. Parse the input using a sate machine
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, ClientData& cd)
{
    // States for our state machine
    enum class States { WaitForDate, ReadDate, WaitForID, WaitForNotes1, WaitForNotes2, ReadNotes};
    // Initially or note map is empty
    cd.notes.clear();

    // Loop conditions
    bool tryToRead{ true }; bool failureDuringRead{ false };
    // Initial state
    States state{ States::WaitForDate };

    // Read all line belonging to this record
    while (tryToRead && !failureDuringRead) {
        std::string line{};
        if (std::getline(is, line)) {
            // State machine to always do the appropiate operation
            switch (state)
            {
            case States::WaitForDate:    // Wait for the line 
                if (line == "DATA/DATE      TIME     TERMINAL") 
                    state = States::ReadDate;  // If found, goto next state
                break;
            case States::ReadDate: 
                {
                    // extract the date and the time
                    std::istringstream iss(line);
                    iss >> cd.date >> cd.time;
                }  
                state = States::WaitForID; // Next:: Wait for the ID string
                break;
            case States::WaitForID:
                // We are waiting for the ID string. Denominated with "ID" or "CARD"
                if ((line.find("CARD:") == 0) || (line.find("ID:") == 0))
                {
                    // Found, extract is string
                    std::string idOrCard{}; // Dummy. Will not be used
                    std::istringstream iss(line);
                    iss >> idOrCard  >> cd.id;
                    state = States::WaitForNotes1; // Next: wait for "Notes" String
                }
                break;
            case States::WaitForNotes1:
                if (line.find("NOTES:") == 0)    // If we can find the NOTES string
                    state = States::WaitForNotes2;  // Then Next: Read the empty line after "NOTES:"
                break;
            case States::WaitForNotes2:
                // Read empty line
                state = States::ReadNotes;
                break;
            case States::ReadNotes:
                // now read the notes. As long as there is data avaliable (and no empty line)
                if (line != "") {
                    std::string usd{}; // Dummy. Will not be used
                    std::istringstream iss(line);
                    // Extract notes
                    unsigned int type{}; unsigned int count{};
                    iss >> type >> usd >> count;
                    // And put it in map
                    cd.notes[type] += count;
                }
                else {
                    // Empty line found. Done with this record. Everything read.
                    tryToRead = false;             // Stop reading lines
                    state = States::WaitForDate;   // Wait for Date again
                }
                break;
            default:
                std::cerr << "Invalid State\n";
                failureDuringRead = true;
                tryToRead = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            // Error while reading
            cd.id.clear(); cd.date.clear(); cd.time.clear(); cd.notes.clear();
            tryToRead = false;
        }
    }
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    // Open input file
    std::ifstream ifs("r:\\input.txt");
    if (ifs) {

        // Read and parse all records with one statement
        std::vector<ClientData> clientData{std::istream_iterator<ClientData>(ifs),std::istream_iterator<ClientData>() };

        // Get total sum of notes
        size_t totalSumOfNotes{ 0 };
        for (const ClientData& cd : clientData) totalSumOfNotes += cd.getNumberOfNotes();

        // Print result in requested format. You can of course replace std::cout by any ofstream
        std::cout << "Total notes: " << totalSumOfNotes << "\n===============================";
        for (size_t i = 0; i < clientData.size(); ++i)  {
            std::cout << '\n' << (i + 1) << ".  " << clientData[i] << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << "===============================\n";
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "Could not open imput file\n";
    return 0;
}
```

We use an object oriented approach and put all data that belong together in a class. Then we will define member functions. And here especially the extractor operator.

In this we use a statemachine. The statemachine is in a current state and waits for something to happen. If a condition is met, an action is executed and we will go to the next state. The condiations are always the strings for which we search. The actions do the work and collect the data.

Very straightforward. Please try to read and understand. If you have further questions, then ask.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when i compile this code it gave me the error for the 'const&[k' , for this line ` size_t getNumberOfNotes() const { size_t sum{ 0 }; for (auto const&[k, v] : notes) sum += v; return sum; } ` `
Error C2429 language feature 'structured bindings' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'  ` 
`Error C2597 illegal reference to non-static member 'ClientData::v' `

Comment: You need to compile with C++ 17 compiler.  Please use compiler flag /std:c++17'

Comment: Why when i add 2 more lines in input file after the last line (PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE) and try to read them after find empty line in **else{} statement** `else {state = States::WaitReadLine;}` by adding new state that read this lines `case States::WaitReadLine: if (line != "") { std::istringstream iss(line); iss >> cd.exp_txt; state = States::WaitForDate; tryToRead = false; }`.Here i have problem that i don't read all NOTES from input file. In my case i have NOTES: with 4 lines and it reads only the first line with notes not all lines.